# Creating Line Graph with iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, graph

I am looking to do a basic line graph on iOS. What library is recommended to pursue to do this? I will also be looking to pull the data points from my Parse backend DB, but that is something I will worry about later.  For now, I just want to be able to create a line graph to display up to 10 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen two nice libriaries that may fit your needs:

- [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot)
- [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts)

Comment: CorePlot looks like the most stable, thank you sir!